# SSRS 2012 diacritics show as black diamond

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, diacritics

I inherited a SSRS report with an issue in it.
It shows the "letter i with 2 dots on top" aka with diacritics as a black diamond with an white questionmark in it and not as an "i with 2 dots on top (hope this is it: ï)
This occurs in the part of the static data of the .rdl file.

So, then it's probably with encoding?

The .rdl file is utf-8, the sql server is most likely "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS".

The report is run on sql 2012, and retrieved by the latest chrome version.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: does the data look correct in your database? if so then make sure the font you are using supports these chararcters

Comment: The black diamonds are part of static text in the .rdl file (will add this to the question too)